# Varnish pass-through route

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a Varnish cache setup in front of my application. I want some routes to be not cached, but completely passed through to other service.
I need to preserve headers like X-Forwarded-For so underlying service won't notice anything.

I've tried "pipe" configuration but it didn't worked as I excepted.
I'm looking for complete config section.

Config I've tried looked like:

```
backend blog {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8083";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blog;
        return (pipe);
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `return(pass)`, which will not serve the content from the cache and connect directly to the backend.

The `return(pipe)` logic is only useful if you're unsure whether or not the incoming request is actually an HTTP request. By piping a request, you take away all notion of HTTP and reduce the data to plain TCP.

Thanks to `return(pass)` all headers are maintained.

Here's an updated version of your code example:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend blog {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8083";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/blog/") {
        set req.backend_hint = blog;
        return (pass);
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried pass also, but for some reason it didn't worked. I'll give it a shot once more, thank you!

Comment: @VladimirRozhkov Please attach the output of the following command to your question : `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ '^/blog.'"`. This will help us understand the `return(pass)` would be failling.

Comment: looks like the pass did the trick. Everything is worked as excepted, thank you!

Comment: For more information see https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/bypass-cache-urls/